# get two specific text from string

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "Anda mendapatkan penambahan pulsa Rp 100000 dari nomor 6282298981111 tgl 2018-07-08. Cek pulsa melalui *888#. Info CS: 188";
```

I want to get text 100000 and 6282298981111 how is the code?

Thanks in advance, I'm new in here

Comment: Hi! Stackoverflow is a specific problem solving community, not a place where we write your code for free. Show us what you have done, where you got stuck and what output you expect. We were all new once, but we learned because we tried and errored!

Comment: As this is your first experience you shouldn't care that much about donwvotes on your question, but listening to comments of peoples explainign why they downvoted is also extremely important. Here, take the [tour] and visit the [ask] page, that should help.

Comment: actually i've tried some code and some code that i try is not working or wrong, sorry

Comment: please update your question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

At the output, get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100000
    [1] => 6282298981111
)
```